# Regular expression to match content until multi-character string

Tags: javascript, regex, html-parsing, regex-negation

I've got defective input coming in that looks like this...

```
foo<p>bar</p>
```

And I want to normalize it to wrap the leading text in a p tag:

```
<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>
```

This is easy enough with the regex replace of `/^([^<]+)/` with `<p>$1</p>`.  Problem is, sometimes the leading chunk contains tags other than p, like so:

```
foo <b>bold</b><p>bar</p>
```

This should wrap the whole chunk in a new p:

```
<p>foo <b>bold</b></p><p>bar</p>
```

But since the simple regex looks only for `<`, it stops at `<b>` and spits out:

```
<p>foo </p><b>bold</b><p>bar</p> <!-- oops -->
```

So how do I rewrite the regex to match `<p`?  Apparently the answer involves negative lookahead, but [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is a bit too deep for me.

(And before the inevitable "you can't parse HTML with regexes!" comment, the input is not random HTML, but plain text annotated with only the tags `<p>`, `<a>`, `<b>` and `<i>`, and a/b/i may not be nested.)

Comment: +1 just for the last sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you actually want *positive* lookahead. It's really not bad:

```
/^([^<]+)(?=<p)/
```

You just want to make sure that whatever comes after `<` is `p`, but you don't want to actually consume `<p`, so you use a lookahead.

Examples:

```
> var re = /^([^<]+)(?=<p)/g;

> 'foo<p>bar</p>'.replace(re, '<p>$1</p>');
  "<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>"

> 'foo <b>bold</b><p>bar</p>'.replace(re, '<p>$1</p>')
  "foo <b>bold</b><p>bar</p>"
```

---

> Sorry, wasn't clear enough in my original posting: my expectation was that the "foo bold" bit would also get wrapped in a new `p` tag, and that's not happening.
>
> Also, every now and then there's input with no `p` tags at all (just plain `foo`), and that should also map to `<p>foo</p>`.

The easiest way I found to get this working is to use 2 separate regexps, `/^(.+?(?=<p))/` and `/^([^<]+)/`.

```
> var re1 = /^(.+?(?=<p))/g,
      re2 = /^([^<]+)/g,
      s = '<p>$1</p>';

> 'foo<p>bar</p>'.replace(re1, s).replace(re2, s);
  "<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>"

> 'foo'.replace(re1, s).replace(re2, s);
  "<p>foo</p>"

> 'foo <b>bold</b><p>bar</p>'.replace(re1, s).replace(re2, s);
  "<p>foo <b>bold</b></p><p>bar</p>"
```

---

It's possible to write a single, equivalent regexp by combining `re1` and `re2`:
`/^(.+?(?=<p)|[^<]+)/`

```
> var re3 = /^(.+?(?=<p)|[^<]+)/g,
      s = '<p>$1</p>';

> 'foo<p>bar</p>'.replace(re3, s)
  "<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>"

> 'foo'.replace(re3, s)
  "<p>foo</p>"

> 'foo <b>bold</b><p>bar</p>'.replace(re3, s)
  "<p>foo <b>bold</b></p><p>bar</p>"
```

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear enough in my original posting: my expectation was that the "foo bold" bit would also get wrapped in a new p tag, and that's not happening.

Comment: Also, every now and then there's input with no p tags at all (just plain `foo`), and that should also map to `<p>foo</p>`.

Comment: The basic idea is quite simply that text should always be wrapped in paragraphs.  The two-regexp style works well, thanks!